# Trouble Creating Dictionary Object For VBA Macro

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary, runtime-error

I am just trying to run the code below but I cannot create the ScriptingDictionary object; I keep getting the error:

Run-time error '429':
ActiveX component can't create object.

I have tried creating the object using the keyword "New" as well and was not successful. Do I need to import any libraries?

Thanks for the help.

```
Option Explicit
Sub GetDuplicates():
    Dim i As Long, arr As Variant, tmp As Variant
    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    arr = Range(Cells(1, "ID"), Cells(Rows.Count, "ID").End(xlUp)).Value
    'build dictionary
    For i = 2 To UBound(arr, 1)
        If dict.exists(arr(i, 1)) Then
            Cells(i, 3).Value = "Repeat"
        Else
            dict.Item(arr(i, 1)) = Array(i)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: There is no method with the name `Item` for dictionaries. It is called `Items`. But `Items` only work with *early binding*. If you use your code because you need the word "Repeat", you can use the `Add` method of the dictionary, because you checked before with `exists`. If you don't need the word "Repeat", you don't need the array and you don't need `Exists`. Read the section *Adding Items to the Dictionary* in the following link. Read also *Assigning a Value* where you don't need the check with `Exists`: https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/

Comment: Another error in your code is, the first element of the array has the index 0 but your loop starts from 2 and what is `Array(i)`?

Comment: Another issue is that you need to make sure that `arr` is a `String` - You will have odd results if it is a `Variant`

Comment: What version of Excel?  MAC or Windows?  `Scripting.Dictionary` is not available on the MAC.  But there is a workaround class published on github.